# Strange color in PSTricks

Tags: color, pstricks, path-clipping

I draw a figure in `pstricks`, the code is here:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{pstricks}
\definecolor{bg}{cmyk}{0,0,0.1,0}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[linewidth=1.5pt](-2,-1.5)(10,4)

\psclip{\psellipse(2.2,1)(2,1.5)}
  \psellipse[fillcolor=blue!20,fillstyle=solid](4.3,1)(2,1.5)
\endpsclip
\psellipse[linecolor=Green](4.3,1)(2,1.5)
\psellipse[linecolor=yellow](2.2,1)(2,1.5)

\psframe[linecolor=blue](-1.5,-1.5)(8,4)
\psframe[linecolor=Maroon,fillstyle=solid](2.8,0.3)(3.8,1.2)


\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

But the yellow ellipse is with not pure yellow, but with some black inside. I tried to change to other color, but it is always there. Why is it like this?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because your clipping polygon/curve has some line width. Remove the line width (`linewidth=none`) and you'll be fine:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{pstricks}% http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi/

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{pspicture}[linewidth=1.5pt](-2,-1.5)(10,4)
  \psclip{\psellipse(2.2,1)(2,1.5)}
    \psellipse[fillcolor=blue!20,fillstyle=solid](4.3,1)(2,1.5)
  \endpsclip
  \psellipse[linecolor=Green](4.3,1)(2,1.5)
  \psellipse[linecolor=yellow](2.2,1)(2,1.5)
  \rput{0}(0,-2){
    \psclip{\psellipse[linestyle=none](2.2,1)(2,1.5)}
      \psellipse[fillcolor=blue!20,fillstyle=solid](4.3,1)(2,1.5)
    \endpsclip
    \psellipse[linecolor=Green](4.3,1)(2,1.5)
    \psellipse[linecolor=yellow](2.2,1)(2,1.5)
  }
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

This is technically a non-issue, since both polygons/curves are drawn on top of one another with the same line width. The visual may show some border at certain zoom levels... however, this is barely at higher zoom levels (the NW-SE line has some visible remnants on the NE side):

[image]

Comment: @Ginger: It actually becomes more evident that the clipping path is redrawn an entirely visible if it doesn't match the path to be clipped. That is, use something like `\psframe(1,0)(5,3)` for the clipping path and you'll see the entire frame still visible. However, setting `linestyle=none` still clips, but without the path showing. Some people prefer `linewidth=0pt`, but you may find some residual line showing.

Comment: this way the problem still exists for the left part of the green ellipse.